# Intel IPP functions for arrays beyond 32-bit size limits?

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit, numerical-methods, intel-ipp

I’m evaluating [Intel IPP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference) to speed up certain parts of our code, e.g.,

- [adding](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-add)
- [absolute value](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/502108)
- [sorting](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-sortradixascend-sortradixdescend)

among others. I note this [page in the manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-guide-using-intel-integrated-performance-primitives-platform-aware-functions):

> While the rest of Intel IPP functions support only signals or images of 32-bit integer size, Intel IPP platform-aware functions work with 64-bit object sizes if it is supported by the target platform. … You can distinguish Intel IPP platform-aware functions by the `L` suffix in the function name, for example, `ippiAdd_8u_C1RSfs_L`. With Intel IPP platform-aware functions you can overcome 32-bit size limitations.

Of the three I mentioned above, it appears only *sorting* has 64-bit-aware functionality.

So, questions: can this be right? Can IPP *not* accelerate addition/abs on arrays beyond 32-bit indexing? Is there a master list of functions that have “platform-aware” (64-bit) alternatives in IPP? Do people hand-roll workarounds to the 32-bit limit, like calling the add/abs functions in a loop over 2^30-sized chunks?

Comment: If you're performing multiple operations on your data then you probably want to strip-mine it anyway, with a chunk size *much* smaller than 2^30 elements.

Comment: @PaulR got it. Does the advice for small chunks hold even if I won't be doing multiple-operations, i.e., just add or abs or conj on an array?

Comment: No, no need to strip-mine if it's just a single operation and there is no possibility of combining it with other operations. If this is the case with simple operations like add/abs though then you will most likely be memory bandwidth-limited and will not see a significant improvement from using optimised routines.